# Woocommerce hiding all prices when user is not logged in (include sales price) en replace by text "you have to be logged in"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to hide all prices when a user is not logged in , in woocommerce.
Including sales prices.
The price must be replaced with a text that the user needs to log in.

The following code works perfectly except sales price from a simpel product

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'update_price_html', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'update_price_html', 10, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html','update_price_html', 10, 2);
function update_price_html( $html, $product ) {
    if(!is_user_logged_in()) {

        add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', '__return_false');
        $html = "Je moet registreerd zijn om de prijzen te zien";

        return $html;
    } else {
        return $html;
    }
}
```

As you can see in the image below, it doesn't work on sale price.
[image: Mixed regular price and sale price]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-hide-price-add-cart-logged-users/

Comment: For info, `woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html` hook doesn't exist any more… Your issue is related to the third party plugin that your are using to display products in a table, as on normal WooCommerce, this problem doesn't exist…

Comment: That tutorial is somehow different but has exactly the same problem and I now why .
The plugin "Woo Discount Rules" is probably conflicting.
Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: Thanks LoicTheAztec, that's indeed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

My code was conflicting with the Woo Discount Rules.

I had the change the priority to 1010.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html','update_price_html', 1010, 2);
```